# Donald Knuth Concrete Mathematics 2nd Edition page 75. I don't understand one of the step of SUM-manipulations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[SUM-manipulations and author's clarifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFCFl.png)

I understand all this SUM-manipulations excluding one moment.

Knuth wrote:

> The only 'difficult' maneuver is the decision made between lines 3
>   and 4 to treat n = 1000 as a special case. 
>   (The inequality $k^3 <= n <(k + 1)^3$ does not combine easily with 
>   $1 <= n <= 1000$ when k =10.)

I didn't get why these 2 inequalities do not combine easily? As for me, they combine fine when k=10 (n=1000 is ok for both inequalities).

But of course, if we leave $[1<=n<=10]$ instead of author's $[1<=n<10]$ we will get another **wrong** answer (W=205).

Could you help me understand the difficulties in smooth combination these two inequalities? Because I don't see the reason for this.

Thank you.

P.S. If you need additional clarification from my side please say me which one.

Comment: "Does not combine easily" does seem an obscure way to explain it. I might say $k^3 \leq n <(k + 1)^3$ does not **enforce the condition that** $1 \leq n \leq 1000$ when $k =10.$ It seems to me we are trying to make the condition $1 \leq n \leq 1000$ redundant so we can stop listing it, not "combine" it with additional conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better not to use images if you can.  They may disappear, and MathJax is readable by more people.  The lines in question are
$$ \sum_{k,n,m} [k^3 \leq n < (k+1)^3] [n=km][1 \leq n \leq 1000] \\ = 1 + \sum_{k,m} [k^3 \leq km < (k+1)^3][1 \leq k < 10]
$$
where $[\cdot ]$ is the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

The point is that they want to eliminate $n$ on the next line but some how keep the restriction "$n \leq 1000$" i.e. $km \leq 1000$. In all cases except $k=10$ that's forced by the $km < (k+1)^3$ and $k\leq 10$ restrictions (as $(k+1)^3 < 1000$ except for $k=10$). That's why they need to make a special case out of $k=10$ on the next line.

For $k=10$ there are more solutions to $k^3\leq km < (k+1)^3$ and $1 \leq k \leq 10$ than there are to $k^3 \leq n <(k+1)^3, n=km, 1 \leq n \leq 1000$ e.g. $k=10, m=101, 102, ...$.

Comment: I think you don't really mean $1\leq k < 10$ in the last paragraph. But I think you made the point anyway.

Comment: thanks, I'll fix it

Comment: Thank you, Matthew. It is true that I lost sight of getting additional solutions like m=101,102, ... if I retain k = 10. Thank you for your advice about MathJax too. I'm going to follow it.